# Normalize vector by zero

Tags: math, language-agnostic, normalization, divide-by-zero

I am working on designing a new sensor, and so I have a vector of measured values and a vector of truth values.  To represent error, it's simply `measured - truth`.  Since there's a lot of variation in the truth, I would like to represent the normalized error.  My initial thought would be `error./truth` to get percent error, but there are many cases where my truth value is zero!  Can anyone think of a better way to represent the normalized data while avoiding the divide-by-zero?  I'm working in Matlab, though the question is a bit language-agnostic as well.

*PS, feel free to push this to another stackexchange if you think it's better suited*

Answer (score 0):

Try `error = (measured-truth)/norm2(truth)` for each vector.

Where `norm2()` is the forbenious norm.

```
norm2(x) =SQRT( SUM( x[i]^2, i=1..N ) )
```

This can only fail is all the values of `truth` are zero. You can mitigate this by adding a small positive number like `1e-12` to the norm, or to avoid the division when the norm is less than a threshold number.

Comment: All this really does is scale all of my values by the same number.  I want to somehow scale each measured point by it's corresponding truth point.

Comment: Well, if your truth point can be `0`, you can't always get what you want.  So, try and spend some time rethinking what you actually need...

Comment: @DavidK - Do not do that. It will be far to unstable and the error estimates will be way off. It is best to normalize the differences against a standard value (either typical, or norm2() or a max(), or arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to separate results with zero (or smaller than 10e-6 for example) truth vector and non-zero truth vector. You can't treat it by the same means (since you can't normalize truth vector) and you should define what to do in that case.
I can't suggest you something specific because I don't know the problem statement, but you should define it by yourself how to deal with it. Or if you post your problem here I hope we can help you.